# Count the number of occurences of a particular value inside loop

Tags: php, arrays

In array count all true where category is 1 after counting the category will move to 2 thn count all true and so on?

Array generated:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $data)
{
    $a = explode("_", $key);

    $f = array(
        'category' => $a[1],
        'answer' => $data
    );
   $f_data[] = $f;
}
```

**FROM**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => true
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => true
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => true
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => false
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => false
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => true
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [category] => 1
            [answer] => true
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => true
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => true
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => true
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => false
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => true
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [answer] => true
        )

)
```

**To**

```
array (
   category: 1,
   count: 5
),
array(
  category: 2,
  count: 5
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
$return = array();
foreach($cont as $item) {
    if($item['answer'] == 'true') {
        $verify = false;
        foreach($return as $key => $value) {
            if($value['category'] == $item['category']) {
                $return[$key]['count']++;
                $verify = true;
                break;
            }    
        }
        if(!$verify)
             $return[] = array('category' => $item['category'], 'count' => 1);
    }
}
```

And this is better solution...

```
$return = array();
foreach($cont as $item) {
    if($item['answer'] == 'true') {
        if(array_key_exists($item['category'], $return))
            $return[$item['category']]++;
        else    
            $return[$item['category']] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I believe this is what you are after (pending any minor mistakes):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $data)
{
    $a = explode("_", $key);

    $f[$a[1]]['category'] = $a[1];

    if ($data == "true") {
        $f[$a[1]]['answer']++;
    }
}
```